# Blank Widgets - Custom Sidebars

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a series of new sidebars for a custom homepage on WordPress. After saving each one, they work and continue to work. Once I return to the Widget area in the Admin area, only those widgets are blank and they are then missing from the home page. Functions.php code below for the added sidebars

```
// Widgetized Header

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Header',
        'id' => 'Header',
        'description' => 'Header Sidebar for Search',
        'before_widget' => '<ul class="right"><li class="has-form">',
        'after_widget' => '</li></ul>',
        'before_title' => '<h4>',
        'after_title' => '</h4>',
    ));
}

// Homepage Sidebar for Mailchimp
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Homepage Mailchimp Widget',
        'id' => 'HomeWidget1',
        'description' => 'Homepage mailchimp area',
        'before_widget' => '<ul class="home-widget"><li class="has-form">',
        'after_widget' => '</li></ul>',
        'before_title' => '<h4>',
        'after_title' => '</h4>',
    ));
}

// Homepage Sidebar for Twitter
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Homepage Twitter Widget',
        'id' => 'HomeWidget2',
        'description' => 'Homepage twitter area',
        'before_widget' => '<ul class="home-widget"><li>',
        'after_widget' => '</li></ul>',
        'before_title' => '<h4>',
        'after_title' => '</h4>',
    ));
}

// Homepage Sidebar for Promo Ad
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Homepage Promo Ad',
        'id' => 'HomeWidget5',
        'description' => 'Homepage Promo Ad',
        'before_widget' => '<ul class="home-widget">',
        'after_widget' => '</ul>',
    ));
}

// Homepage Sidebar for Archives
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Homepage Archive Widget',
        'id' => 'HomeWidget3',
        'description' => 'Homepage Widget for Archives',
        'before_widget' => '<ul class="home-widget"><li class="has-form">',
        'after_widget' => '</li></ul>',
        'before_title' => '<h4>',
        'after_title' => '</h4>',
    ));
}


// Homepage Sidebar for Archives
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Homepage Social Widget',
        'id' => 'HomeWidget4',
        'description' => 'Homepage Widget for Social Nav',
        'before_widget' => '<ul class="home-widget"><li>',
        'after_widget' => '</li></ul>',
        'before_title' => '<h4>',
        'after_title' => '</h4>',
    ));
}
```

Comment: Have you added  `<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-id' ); ?>` to the homepage for each widget?

Comment: Yes. They work. It's the actual widgets area that goes black. The default sidebar stays filled up with widgets though.

Comment: Check the source of the page and see if the contents are actually there, but just the same colour as the background?

Comment: That's the thing - when I got BACK to the widgets page, they are gone and ALSO they disappear from the homepage. If I never return to the widget page, they're fine and still on the homepage. Odd.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using that if statement, instead of adding the register_sidebar in the `twentytwelve_widgets_init()` function?

Comment: only reason would be that's how I saw it in the tutorial :\

Comment: I should note that this is a child theme and this is the functions.php file of the child theme

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be causing that problem.

1) register_sidebar() doesn't need to be wrapped in a conditional here. It's a WordPress core function, so it ain't going anywhere. This will do just fine:

```
 register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Homepage Twitter Widget',
    'id' => 'HomeWidget2',
    'description' => 'Homepage twitter area',
    'before_widget' => '<ul class="home-widget"><li>',
    'after_widget' => '</li></ul>',
    'before_title' => '<h4>',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));
```

2) Use action hook `widgets_init` to load the registrations. For multiple instances of register_sidebar, I would recommend wrapping all instances in a function, and then hooking that function. Ex:

```
function myPrefix_widgets_init() {
        register_sidebar(array(
                'name' => 'Homepage Mailchimp Widget',
                'id' => 'HomeWidget1',
                'description' => 'Homepage mailchimp area',
                'before_widget' => '<ul class="home-widget"><li class="has-form">',
                'after_widget' => '</li></ul>',
                'before_title' => '<h4>',
                'after_title' => '</h4>',
));
// Register the rest of the widgets here.
```

}

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'myPrefix_widgets_init' ); //<-- This is the action hook
```

This post from Justin Tadlock is a few years old now, but still fantastic at explaining in detail how WordPress wants to handle widgetized sidebars: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/11/08/sidebars-in-wordpress

Comment: I tried both methods and when I refresh the widgets pages those new sidebars go blank.